# SharePoint 2010 search and mp4 files

Tags: search

I have two 2010 environments .  On one, i am able to search for mp4 files ( on enviro A) by using 'FileExtension:mp4' but not on other ( environ B).  On B i am running sharepoint 2010 service pack 2 while A has SP1 only.

I have already added mp4 extension to sharepoint search file types, made sure that mp4 is not added in restricted file types. But still search on B is not showing the search results.

Also, on A in Manage File Types page of search applicatin, it says 'mp4 document; but on B it says 'mp4 video'.

Any idea?

Comment: did you run the full crawl on Env B? what error you are getting?